# Adding rows to complete a discontinuous summary table in R

Tags: r

I'm creating tables using `groupby` and `summarize` with years as rows. Some of the output tables do not have continuous years (because there are no values for those years), such as the following:

```
> df
  Year A B
1 1999 1 3
2 2002 5 9
3 2004 6 9
```

I am looking for a way to automate filling in missing years for a pre-determined span (1998-2004 in this example) and filling the added rows with 0. I am able to add individual rows manually using `add_row` but would like a way to automate this, without previously knowing which years are missing.

```
df %>% add_row("Year" = c("1998","2000","2001","2003"), "A" = 0, "B" = 0)

> df
  Year A B
1 1998 0 0
2 1999 1 3
3 2000 0 0
4 2001 0 0
5 2002 5 9
6 2003 0 0
7 2004 6 9
```

Comment: You can do `df %>% complete(year = as.character(1998:2004), fill = list(A = 0, B = 0))`, more detail here: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. There really is a function for everything!